# How to represent a binary tree with tables (html)?

Tags: php, html-table, binary-tree, data-representation

Here is a brain-teaser for the brave. I've been at it for days and just can't come with the solution.

I wanted to come out with something like this:

[image]

Using html, CSS and PHP only.

I got near, but not quite what I expected. [Here is the code in PHP](http://ideone.com/JmhHB) and [here is the output](http://jsfiddle.net/naoise/u5fFk/show/).

```
<table border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Cientoveintiochavos</th>
        <th>Seseintaicuatravos</th>
        <th>Treintaidosavos</th>
        <th>Dieciseisavos</th>
        <th>Octavos</th>
        <th>Cuartos</th>
        <th>Semifinales</th>
        <th>Final</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php for($i=0;$i<256;$i++): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php for($n=0,$c=2;$n<8;$n++,$c*=2): ?>
            <?php 
            /*
            if(false){//$i == 0) {
                $rwspn = $c/2+1; 
                $iter = 0;
            } else {
                $rwspn = $c; 
                $iter = $c;//-$c/2+1;
            } 
            */
            $class = ($i%($c*2))?'par':'impar winner';
            if($i%$c==0):?>
                <td rowspan="<?=$c;?>" class="<?=$class;?>"><span><?php echo genRandomString();?></span></td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>   
<?php endfor; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If someone knows how to represent a binary tree or a dendrogram or comes up with a smarter code please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something like this, using divs kinda like @HugoDelsing. The way I handled the lines was to divide each pair into 4 vertically-stacked divs:

1. The first player (border-bottom)
2. A spacer between 1st and 2nd players (border-right)
3. The second player (border-bottom and border-right)
4. A spacer before the next pair (no borders)

Each of these gets 1/4 the height of the pair*, and the total height of a pair gets doubled as you move to the right. If you don't have a power of two, fill slots with placeholders to push everything down the right amount.

*The bottom borders will throw the heights off by 1, so take that into account when styling your rows.

**Other Notes**
The spacer divs may not be necessary, but for me they easily handled the spacing and getting the different columns to line up correctly.

I used inline styles filled-in by PHP for the heights, so I didn't have an arbitrary depth limit or calculations hard-coded into CSS.

[Here's an example.](http://www.underdogseattle.com/bracket/1871/)

**EDIT**
OK, here is teh codez:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .round{
        float:left;
        width:200px;
    }
    .firstTeam, .secondTeam{
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        position:relative;
    }
    .firstSpacer, .secondTeam{
        border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .team{
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 4px;
        left: 8px;
    }
</style>
<div class="round">
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team One</div></div>
        <div class="firstSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team Two</div></div>
        <div class="secondSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team Three</div></div>
        <div class="firstSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team Four</div></div>
        <div class="secondSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team Five</div></div>
        <div class="firstSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team Six</div></div>
        <div class="secondSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team Seven</div></div>
        <div class="firstSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondTeam" style="height:29px;"><div class="team">Team Eight</div></div>
        <div class="secondSpacer" style="height:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="round">
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:59px;"><div class="team">Team One</div></div>
        <div class="firstSpacer" style="height:60px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondTeam" style="height:59px;"><div class="team">Team Three</div></div>
        <div class="secondSpacer" style="height:60px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:59px;"><div class="team">Team Five</div></div>
        <div class="firstSpacer" style="height:60px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondTeam" style="height:59px;"><div class="team">Team Eight</div></div>
        <div class="secondSpacer" style="height:60px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="round">
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:119px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="firstSpacer" style="height:120px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondTeam" style="height:119px;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="secondSpacer" style="height:120px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="round">
    <div class="matchup">
        <div class="firstTeam" style="height:239px;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you paste an example of the code or a jsfiddle for easier visualization? looks just what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt use a table but divs.

- create a column container div with relative/absolute position with a fixed width (eg: 200px) for each col.
- Each column container has inner divs with a height and lineheight of double the previous column container
- create a long black vertical line image (length atleast the half the size of the largest height of inner divs in any column. Start the line with a horizontal line of 200px wide to the left (so rotate an L with 180degrees). Leave about half the text height of free space above the horizontal line in the image, so the line will be under the text.
- set this image as background to the inner div of each column container and position it at left center; repeat = none;

Some sample code (without images)

```
<style type="text/css">
div.col { position:absolute;border:1px solid #f00;width:200px;top:0px; }
div.col1 { left:0px; }
div.col1 div { height:20px; line-height:20px; }
div.col2 { left:200px; }
div.col2 div { height:40px; line-height:40px; }
div.col3 { left:400px; }
div.col3 div { height:80px; line-height:80px; }
div.col4 { left:600px; }
div.col4 div { height:160px; line-height:160px; }
div.col5 { left:800px; }
div.col5 div { height:320px; line-height:320px; }
</style>


<div class='col1 col'>
    <div>player1</div>
    <div>player2</div>
    <div>player3</div>
    <div>player4</div>
    <div>player5</div>
    <div>player6</div>
    <div>player7</div>
    <div>player8</div>
    <div>player9</div>
    <div>player10</div>
    <div>player11</div>
    <div>player12</div>
    <div>player13</div>
    <div>player14</div>
    <div>player15</div>
    <div>player16</div>
</div>
<div class='col2 col'>
    <div>player1</div>
    <div>player3</div>
    <div>player5</div>
    <div>player7</div>
    <div>player9</div>
    <div>player11</div>
    <div>player13</div>
    <div>player15</div>
</div>
<div class='col3 col'>
    <div>player1</div>
    <div>player5</div>
    <div>player9</div>
    <div>player13</div>
</div>
<div class='col4 col'>
    <div>player1</div>
    <div>player9</div>
</div>
<div class='col5 col'>
    <div>player1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting approach. I've done a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/naoise/ez5N2/) but still can't see how to manage the lines like in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're almost there. Nice work! I think the center alignment you want is in CSS

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I don't think you can get the lines to work using borders. You might try a background image for them instead.

Comment: that's right, the lines won't work so that is not the solution (♫ niau niau niau, better luck next time! ♫)
Actually there is more to it than meets the eye. I have a few papers with representations and formula's, that do a good approximation, but something is missing and can't continue with it at the moment. Maybe has a more simpler approximation.